# Merge two Excel sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, merge

I have two 'tabs' in my Excel file and I would like to merge the two tabs into one sheet (in the same file).

The two files look somthing like:

```
artnr      language       description      price
artnr      language       description      price
artnr      language       description      price
```

What I would like to do is merge those two files in the following manner:

```
first row of first sheet
first row of second sheet
second row of first sheet
second row of second sheet
etc.
```

I tried to use the following formula:

```
=Sheet1!A1
=Sheet2!A1
=Sheet1!A2
=Sheet2!A2
```

This works, however when I try to expand the formula down (to the other rows) I get:

```
=Sheet1!A1
=Sheet2!A1
=Sheet1!A2
=Sheet2!A2
=Sheet1!A5
=Sheet2!A5
```

In stead of:

```
=Sheet1!A1
=Sheet2!A1
=Sheet1!A2
=Sheet2!A2
=Sheet1!A3
=Sheet2!A3
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not require the referencing to the original cells, you could do this another way.

First, in sheet 1 row 1; enter odd numbers on the cell to the right starting with 1 and drag the pattern to the last row

```
first row | 1
second row | 3
third row | 5
...
```

...and the same for sheet 2; except you use even numbers starting with 2.

Finish off by copying sheet 1 rows (including the numbering) below sheet 2 rows and do a sort by numbering column.

Comment: Now that's a simple and working solution! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

Put the following formula in A1 of your third sheet:

```
=IF(ROW(A1)/2=INT(ROW(A1)/2);Sheet2!A1;Sheet1!A1)
```

and then copy&paste in the rows below.